# Program to decompress WaveZip on 64-bit

Tags: software, compression

Anyone know of a 64-bit or 32-bit windows compatible program to WaveZip compressed files?  I just tried to install WaveZip on my 64-bit Windows machine and it is 16-bit and won't install.

Comment: I keep a virtual machine specifically for WaveZIP and would be happy to help anyone who is stuck without another option to unlock their files. I'll nicely ask for a small donation if the service is worthy to you. Email douglasricketts@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a 32 bit machine where you can install WaveZip, I would recommend decompressing whatever files you have.

If you still want to store them in a compressed format, you can convert them to [flac](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) or [another lossless format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_data_compression) that supports compression.